# Draw Polygon within Panel of Swing GUI Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, drawing

I am trying to figure out how to use DrawPolygon within a Panel of a Swing GUI while learning the basics of Java GUI.

This is the code for generating the panel of the Swing GUI:

```
polygonArea = new javax.swing.JPanel(){
       protected void poly(Graphics g) {
      int xpoints[] = {35, 10, 25, 60, 20};
int ypoints[] = {105, 25, 5, 105, 25};
int xpoints2[] = {60, 70, 92, 80, 82};
int ypoints2[] = {105, 25, 5, 105, 25};
int xpoints3[] = {102, 98, 145, 107};
int ypoints3[] = {5, 105, 105, 100};
int npoints = 5;
int npointsl = 4;

g.fillPolygon(xpoints, ypoints, npoints);
g.fillPolygon(xpoints2, ypoints2, npoints);
g.fillPolygon(xpoints3, ypoints3, npointsl);
      }
    };
    polygonArea.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(240, 240, 240));
```

Based off generated GUI from Netbeans. I am really new to Java, but when I launch the file it appears like this:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KsIo.jpg

Instead of the poly function on its own which displays:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrAsK.png

Sorry if it's a pretty obvious error, any help would be much appreciated!

(Can't post images due to reputation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `poly` is not invoked automatically in the paint stack in Swing. You need to do this explicitly for example

```
class PolyPanel extends JPanel {
    protected void poly(Graphics g) {
       ...  
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        poly(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, it says it cannot find the symbol JComponent? Again sorry if this is something simple I am missing, thank you!

Comment: Actually `JComponent` doesnt do any custom painting itself so its easiest to stick to using `JPanel` for the background color, have removed that footnote :)

Comment: That was exactly the issue, I had imported javax.swing.* but it wasn't working. Adding an import for javax.swing.JComponent fixed this for some reason. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Override the function from JPanel, `paintComponent(Graphics g)` and call `poly(Graphics g)` from it. Something like this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   super.paintComponent(g);
   poly(g);
}
```